# Java jtable allow row selection

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to make a jtable which displays a list of users. The table should allow users to select an entire row but not allow editing of the cells.

So far i have this, it stops them from editing cells but how to i allow them to select the rows instead of cells?

```
DefaultTableModel userTableModel = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Customer ID", "First Name", "Last Name"}, 0) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

And this i show i am populating the table:

```
public void refreshCustomersList() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

    UserBeanList userList = dbConnector.getUserData();

    for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
        UserBean userBean = userList.getUserBeanAt(i);

        String[] data = new String[3];

        data[0] = userBean.getCustomerID();
        data[1] = userBean.getFirstName();
        data[2] = userBean.getLastName();

        userTableModel.addRow(data);

    }
    tableCustomers.setModel(userTableModel);
}
```

As i said i have disabled cell editing but how do i only allow row selection.

I have seen posts from other people saying i should put this but i not sure were to put it.

```
selectionTable.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried `setRowSelectionAllowed(true)` on your JTable instance?

I would suggest trying to look at the javadocs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setRowSelectionAllowed(boolean)

and read the tutorial linked from the javadocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

They are pretty thorough :)

Answer (score 0):

```
private void jTable1MousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     

int selectedRow;

ListSelectionModel rowSM = jTable1.getSelectionModel();

  rowSM.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) 
    {
        ListSelectionModel lsm = (ListSelectionModel) e.getSource();

        selectedRow = lsm.getMinSelectionIndex();

        int numCols = jTable1.getColumnCount();

        model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();

        System.out.print(" \n row " + selectedRow + ":");

        for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) 
        {
            System.out.print(" " + model.getValueAt(selectedRow, j));
        }

    }
});
}
```

Using this you can get value of whole row where u click on particular row.